# Css transitions and div

Tags: css, html, background, css-transitions

I have such dom structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="style1"> ... another divs ... </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="style2"> ... another divs ... </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="style1"> ... another divs ... </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="style2"> ... another divs ... </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="style1"> ... another divs ... </div>
</div>
```

In `style1` and `style2` there is `background-color` settings for all inner divs (marked as 'another divs').

Now I want to make background transation for all divs inside `style1` and `style2`:

```
.wrapper :hover
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper
{
    -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background .2s linear;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}
```

It doesn't work (nothing changes). When I set hover propery for `style1` and `style2` it changes background, but only active dive the mouse is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between .wrapper and :hover. But I may have mis-read this. You might want to do `.wrapper:hover .style1 div{}`

Comment: The problem was in space between selector and `:hover` :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you want to show/mark every div that has certain style. So upon hovering single div.style1 you want to mark all style1 divs. I don't know how to achieve this only with css buth with a little jquery/javascript help I got something like this:

**CHANGED CSS**

```
.wrapper_hover
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.wrapper
{
    -moz-transition: background .2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background .2s linear;
    transition: background .2s linear;
}
```

**JQUERY CODE**

```
$("div").hover(
              function () {
                    $(".style1").addClass("wrapper_hover");    
            },
              function () {
                    $(".style1").removeClass("wrapper_hover");   
            }    
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I knew how to do it with JQuery.